# How to find out the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it linear transformation?

> Let the transformation be defined as $T:\mathbb{R}^3  \to  \mathbb{R}$
>   $$T([x, y, z])=x^2-2y+3z$$

Well actually I have no idea how it works with an equation like this.

Comment: Is it $T(x,y,z)=x^2-2y+3z$ or $T(x,y,z)=2x-2y+3z?$

Comment: Sorry you are right well the first one.T(x,y,z)=x^2−2y+3z

Comment: Try to check the definition of a linear map directly.

Comment: If $T$ is linear then you have $T(2,0,0)=2T(1,0,0).$ Does $T$ satisfies such equality?

Comment: yes that's what i thought x=-1 or x= 1 so that's not linear transformation. Am i right?

Comment: What do you mean by $x=-1$ or $x=1?$

Answer (score 1):

The statement "$T$ is linear" in this case means that for $x,x',y,y',z,z' \in \Bbb R$ and any $a \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
T[x+x',y+y',z+z'] = T[x,y,z] + T[x',y',z']\\
T[ax,ay,az] = aT[x,y,z]
$$
You should try to show that $T$ is not linear by finding a set of values such that one of the above equalities does **not** hold.